# How to solve for Temperature $T$ in Richardson Law?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Just wondering for the [Richardson's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission#Richardson.27s_law) for thermionic emission:

$$J=AT^2e^{(-W/kT)}$$

where $J =$ emission current density, $A =$ Richardson Constant, T = Temperature, W = Work Function and k = Boltzmann constant, how best do you approximate for value T given all other figures?

Comment: numerically ...

Comment: In terms of elementary functions, you cant. But mathematicians invented a function that that solve this for you: see [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 1):

Lets get started:

$$
J = AT^2e^{-W/kT} \\
J/A = T^2e^{-W/kT} \\
A/J = T^{-2}e^{W/kT} \\
(A/J)^{1/2} = T^{-1}e^{W/2kT} \\
W/2k\cdot(A/J)^{1/2} = W/2k\cdot T^{-1}e^{W/2kT} \\
$$

Therefore, if we let $\alpha = W/2k$
$$
\alpha\left(\frac{A}{J}\right)^{1/2} = \frac{\alpha}{T}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha}{T}\right)
$$

Taking the Lambert $W$-Function on both sides:
$$
W\left(\alpha\left(\frac{A}{J}\right)^{1/2}\right) = \frac{\alpha}{T}
$$

After all, $W(xe^x) = x$, by definition. Now we simply isolate $T$:
$$
T = \left[\frac{1}{\alpha}W\left(\alpha\sqrt{\frac{A}{J}}\right)\right]^{-1}
$$